# Not able to edit component in chrome in AEM 6.1 in classic UI

Tags: google-chrome, aem, aem-6

This is a very strange issue. I have component that has multiple tabs each tab has a parsys cq:include'ed in it. In these parsys I author components.

Say,

tab-1-parsys> author text component **txt1**

tab-2-parsys> author another text component **txt2**

When I refresh the page I am no longer able to edit **txt1**

The rollover edit(green box) doesn't appear. I edited the text components editConfig to

cq:layout = editbar

Still the issue persists.

If I click tab1-> I cannot see the editbar,

if I clik tab2->  I can see editbar of the same text component.

And most important of them all this **happens only in chrome** all other browsers like firefox and IE show the edit bar of tab1.

So I am certain that this has nothing to do with the AEM component as the other browsers are showing the "rollover edit/editbar"

What could be causing such type of an issue? Does this have to do with incorrect wrapper divs generated by AEM but then why only chrome is the next question ?

Please refer image below.[image]

Comment: are you seeing any errors in chrome developer console?

Comment: @SubhashSulanthar No errors mate.

Comment: I've experienced the same issue once - turned out to be caused by a self closing div tag which was corrected differently in chrome than in other browsers. Other than that, have you verified that the edit html is there and just not visible or edit context is not initialized?

Comment: @3xil3 I'll look for the `<div/>` tag. I don't understand what you mean by edit html or edit context?

Comment: By edit html I mean the html produced by AEM to render the editbar. It's possible that it is rendered, but 0px high, or in a different place in the HTML, or worse, is actually under the editbar of the second component (2 editbars overlaying one another in a visual way). 
By edit context I mean the js/jsp/sightly context which takes special circumstances into account - like cq:editConfig, cq:listeners, cq:noDecoration, cq:htmlTag, wcmmode.disabled, selectors, and so on ... all of these can impact the behaviour and html while under edit mode in combination with component state

Comment: As a side note - I'd look into what happens if you render both components outside the tabs and basically beneath each other using the same component. It would allow you to verify if the editbar rendering is picked up correctly by AEM or not.